# How to remove spaces present after some letters but not others in PowerPoint

Tags: fonts, microsoft-powerpoint, formatting, kerning

Some letters in my PowerPoint have a space after them that is seemingly impossible to remove. I've tried changing font, adjusting kerning, and character spacing. Nothing removes the spaces. An example of the alphabet is below:

[image]

Comment: Please include an example in the form of a PowerPoint file, otherwise we may only guess what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without knowing where the text is coming from.
Did you type it in?
Did you copy the the text from some source? Word processor or other graphics app?

Probably you could try the following

###### Author your text in Word

Work with the text in Word. Switch on formatting characters. Probably you have some non-breaking spaces in your text. The Velocity line contains non-breaking spaces. Like:

[image: formatting in Word]

1. Copy text to word. Switch on Format Control Character
2. Modify Text (like remove non-breaking spaces)
3. Copy back to PowerPoint

###### If you paste your text from some other sources, paste without formatting

1. Ctrl + Alt + V > unformatted text
2. Right click > Paste Options > Keep Text Only
3. edit text

Like:
[image: paste plain text]

###### some other obscure ideas

If you copy a text-like objects from another application, like SVG graphics editor, the "text" is inserted as an object. I think you can convert this object to a PowerPoint shape. Works great for shapes but not for text (AFAIK). Like this:

[image: Text as Objects]

In the third column I modified the text in an SVG editor (text to SVG paths), pushed some chars back an forth an highlighted the fixed space with a red rectangle to make it clear.